# Poor coding or what

Tags: performance, memory, text, memory-management, memo

So I jave Cubot J3 smartphone and I was using default Calendar app of the phone.
After entering the text in reminder I saved It and after that half of text vanished.
Is there a way to retrieve that data?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. General Android questions belong on the Android site, although I suspect this would be offtopic there as well. You should just contract the developer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for advice, It is best to contact the developer but I doubt that I will get answers.